# How to remove str. Of spaces from list

Tags: python, string, list, helper, spaces

A = ["a","b","    ","c","  ","d"]
How can I remove str. Of white spaces from this list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A = [s for s in A if s.strip() != '']

or

A = [s for s in A if len(s.strip()) > 0]

Comment: Because empty strings '' evaluate to false you can simplify even more;
A = [s for s in A if s.strip()]

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [s for s in A if s.strip()]
```

The above code works because empty strings - ie '' - evaluate to False.